# "admin://" in front of directory in HDD

Tags: 22.04

After updating from 18.04 to 22.04, I realize when I drag a directory in an HDD to terminal, there is always a prefix "admin://" in front of the real directory. I was able to modify the accessibility of the directory by sudo chmod 777, but could not get rid of the annoying "admin://"